# ReactJS partially renders the old state after page refresh instead of rendering the updated and persisted state causing old and new states to show up

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rendering, react-typescript, react-query

Overall, this react app seems to function as expected. **However, when the page is refreshed, only part of the changed state is persisted and correctly re-rendered**, while the other part is reset back to the default state.

> If I go back to VS code and make any irrelevant changes (e.g. Add a comment), save, then go back to the browser, that default state would then gets updated and rendered again correctly.

**So it seems like the reflection of the new state is delayed by 1 step**, but I'm not sure what exactly is causing this weird behaviour.

Data is fetched using `react-query` v.5

Here is the code in the component:

```
const tempU = [
        {
            id: 0,
            name: 'metric',
            symbol: 'C'
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'imperial',
            symbol: 'F'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'standard',
            symbol: 'K'
        },
    ]



const WeatherDisplay = () => {


    const [currentPosition] = useAtom(currentPositionAtom)
    const [, clearCoordinates] = useAtom(clearCoordinatesAtom)
    const [tempUnitID, setTempUnitID] = useAtom(tempUnitIDAtom)


    const selectedTempUnitName = tempU[tempUnitID] && tempU[tempUnitID].name

    // This logs the state correctly everytime 
    console.log('selectedTempUnitName: ', selectedTempUnitName)



    const { data: weatherData, refetch } = useGetCurrentWeather({ 
        currentPosition, 
        selectedTempUnitName
    })


    return (
        <div className={`${style['WeatherDisplay']}`}>
            <h1 className={`${style['temperature']}`}>
                <span onClick={setTemperatureUnitHandler}>


       // This shows old state after a page reload: (State persisted, but delayed by 1 step)
                    {weatherData?.main && Math.round(weatherData?.main.temp)}


                    // This always shows up correctly
                    °{tempU[tempUnitID].symbol}
                </span>
            </h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default WeatherDisplay;
```

Here is what it looks like on the browswer:

Directly after page refreshed. Notice console logs the default state in the first log before the latest state follows. The state from API is not immediately re-rendered for some reason.

[image: Directly after page refreshed]

After an irrelevant change made to code (e.g. Add a comment) and editor is saved, only then the latest state is correctly reflected in the browser. **This delay is unexpected and shouldn't happen.** Notice the log in the console still shows the correct state.
[image: After irrelevant changes made to code and saved, the latest state is reflected]

Here is the link to the repo: https://github.com/iceyisaak/weatherapp/blob/tanstack-query/src/components/WeatherDisplay/index.tsx#L86

Any help is very much appreciated :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROBLEM FINALLY SOLVED!!! :D !!

The solution to this very problem is SO DECEPTIVELY SIMPLE I couldn't believe it!!!

The bug is caused by the lack of initial value in the `tempUnitID`, causing the state to be rendered according to the default state assigned!

In the `SearchBar.tsx`, I use `useEffect()` to check for any saved initial value of the `tempUnitID`.

If no `tempUnitID` value was saved initially, just `setTempUnitID(0)` so that the `WeatherDisplay.tsx` can detect it and use it to render the correct state.

Thank you very much for reading :D !!!

```
    const [tempUnitID, setTempUnitID] = useAtom(tempUnitIDAtom)


    useEffect(() => {
        if (!tempUnitID) {
            setTempUnitID(0)
        }
    }, [tempUnitID])
```